# Format String containing decimal values to Number using Scala

Tags: scala

Format String containing decimal values to Number using Scala

For example if `var a="34.523"` after formatting should be "34523".

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.` with empty string?

```
scala> "12.343".replaceAll("\\.", "")
res0: String = 12343
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also:

```
a.replace(".","")
```